# How to calculate values in a record within grid(GWT)

Tags: gwt, sum, field

```gwt
amount.setAlign(Alignment.RIGHT);                   
        amount.setRecordSummaryFunction(RecordSummaryFunctionType.MULTIPLIER);  
        amount.setSummaryFunction(SummaryFunctionType.SUM);  
        amount.setShowGridSummary(true);  
        amount.setShowGroupSummary(true);  
        amount.setCellFormatter(new CellFormatter() {  
            public String format(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {  
                if (value == null) return null;  
                try {  
                    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00");  
                    return  nf.format(((Number) value).doubleValue());  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                    return value.toString();  
                }  
            }  
        });  



        ShipCost.setType(ListGridFieldType.FLOAT); 
        ShipCostIn.setType(ListGridFieldType.FLOAT); 
        LvingCost.setType(ListGridFieldType.FLOAT); 
        allowance.setType(ListGridFieldType.FLOAT); 
        amount.setType(ListGridFieldType.FLOAT);
```

Amount is a field name and I want to sum it by these feilds' values.
I thought the code can do,but,no....
Thx for your answers.

Comment: can you present which error you are getting?

Comment: No error.I just can not make the function within a record but not a field.

Comment: It can statistics ShipCost,ShipCostIn separately.But I wanna plus them into "amount". Thank you.